# How to match an exact string of digits with bash regular expression?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to match and exact number with regex but It's only matching the first digit.

Here's a sample of the text I'm working with:

```
0x03600007  0 1206   km-Inspiron-3593 ~ : bash — Konsole
0x04c00002  0 15610  km-Inspiron-3593 Minecraft 1.7.10
```

And here's my code:

```
regex="^0x[0-9a-z]{8}[[:space:]]+-?[0-9][[:space:]]15610"
[[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH}"
```

I'm trying to get the value in the first column where the third column is a known value (15610 in this case). So the expression should match `0x04c00002  0 15610` (and I would capture first value from that) but it's only matching `0x03600007  0 1` (the remaining 4 digits are ignored).

For additional context, this text is the output of `wmctrl -lp`, first column is a window ID, second column is PID. So what I'm looking to extract is the window ID given a known PID.

I've tried things like `\b` (AFAIK this is for exact alphabetic word matches), brackets, quotes, no quotes.

Comment: Do all lines of the input look like this or must the line match this format before extracting the hex number?

Comment: Yes, all lines are in this format

Comment: with `BASH_VERSION='5.0.17(1)-release'` I get `0x04c00002  0 15610` as output from your code. You have probably been downvoted, because it is not super clear about what output you require. Rather an include that in a sentence, highlight it with a separate paragraph header and just mono-font text, i.e. `0x04c00002  0 15610` (or whatever you need). (I didn't downvote). Good luck.

Comment: That's good to know but I'd prefer to find a better/more direct solution. Thanks for the feedback, I'll try to make that clearer.

Comment: please update the question to show what you're expecting to be in `BASH_REMATCH`; do you want just the hex code (ie, 1st field) from each line? do you want the first 3 fields from each line? do you only want the hex code (or first 3 fields) if the 3rd field == `15610`?

Comment: @markp-fuso I've updated it, hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: As a rule, `declare -p BASH_REMATCH` is more useful than `echo "$BASH_REMATCH"`. The former shows you the whole array, the latter only shows you the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated after OP's latest update:

```
regex="(0x[0-9a-z]{8})[ ]+0[ ]+15610[ ]+"

while read -r line; do echo "###### $line"; [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]] && typeset -p BASH_REMATCH; done < file

###### 0x03600007  0 1206   km-Inspiron-3593 ~ : bash — Konsole
###### 0x04c00002  0 15610  km-Inspiron-3593 Minecraft 1.7.10
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="0x04c00002  0 15610  " [1]="0x04c00002")
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Where:

- for the matching row we see `BASH_REMATCH[0]` matches the entire regex while ...
- `BASH_REMATCH[1]` matches the desired substring (ie, 1st column)

Or if we want to make sure the hex string is at the start of the line (and filter out the rest of the line):

```
regex="^(0x[0-9a-z]{8})[ ]+0[ ]+15610[ ]+.*$"                                                             

while read -r line; do echo "###### $line"; [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]] && typeset -p BASH_REMATCH; done < file

###### 0x03600007  0 1206   km-Inspiron-3593 ~ : bash — Konsole
###### 0x04c00002  0 15610  km-Inspiron-3593 Minecraft 1.7.10
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="0x04c00002  0 15610  km-Inspiron-3593 Minecraft 1.7.10" [1]="0x04c00002")
                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Replacing the `BASH_REMATCH` approach with a comparison of columns:

```
regex="0x[0-9a-z]{8}"

while read -r line
do 
    echo "####### $line"
    read -r c1 c2 c3 rest_of_line <<< "$line"
    [[ "$c1" =~ $regex && "$c3" = "15610" ]] && echo "$c1"
done < file

####### 0x03600007  0 1206   km-Inspiron-3593 ~ : bash — Konsole
####### 0x04c00002  0 15610  km-Inspiron-3593 Minecraft 1.7.10
0x04c00002

# or

while read -r c1 c2 c3 rest_of_line
do   
    echo "####### $c1 $c2 $c3 $rest_of_line"
    [[ "$c1" =~ $regex && "$c3" = "15610" ]] && echo "$c1"
done < file

####### 0x03600007 0 1206 km-Inspiron-3593 ~ : bash — Konsole
####### 0x04c00002 0 15610 km-Inspiron-3593 Minecraft 1.7.10
0x04c00002
```

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso, this has solved my problem. After going through your solutions I realized `^` only works for the beginning of the entire string and not each line.

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`

```
awk '$3 == 15610{print $1}' file
0x04c00002
```

Comment: perhaps `awk 'NF = $3 == 15610'` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed a repetition pattern. Using the first example:

`0x03600007  0 1206   km-Inspiron-3593 ~ : bash — Konsole`

with the provided regex:

```
original: `^0x[0-9a-z]{8}[[:space:]]+-?[0-9][[:space:]]`

first step: `^0x[0-9a-z]{8}[[:space:]]+` -> `0x03600007  `

second step: `-?` -> matches empty

third step: `[0-9][[:space:]]` -> `0 `
```

I'm guessing the extra digit came from the end of the regex, namely, the literal `15610`.

If you want the full number, this regex might be better suited:

`^0x[0-9a-z]{8}[[:space:]0-9]+[[:space:]]`

Note the section `[[:space:]0-9]+`. If you only want the second number, you can probably make `[0-9]` be the only repetition. The regex I'm suggesting would allow you to continue your capture of the remaining of the text

```bash
regex="^0x[0-9a-z]{8}[[:space:]0-9]+[[:space:]]"
[[ "0x03600007  0 1206   km-Inspiron-3593 ~ : bash — Konsole" =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH}"
```

Comment: This ignores the value in the third column. I want to get the first value when the third value is known. I've updated the question to make it clearer.